# How do i check someones balance?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So like im trying to get my bot to have a command that checks someone elses balance in a economy thing. This is my code. I dont know what ive done wrong...

```
async def check(ctx,member:discord.Member):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = discord.Member
    
    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(discord.Member)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(discord.Member)]["bank"]

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = f"{discord.Member}'s balance",
        Colour = discord.Colour.red()
    )
    embed.set_author(name='Author Name', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Wallet', value= wallet_amt, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Bank', value= bank_amt, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: What does your code do which makes you think what have you done wrong?

Comment: ... Its supposed to send an embed of another users currency balance... Its wrong cause it doesnt send the embed of the other users balance

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming you used `@client.command()` above your function, there are still a couple of things that need some tinkering. First, your `check` function's `member` argument is never actually called and you're opening the account for the specific user that sent the command here `await open_account(ctx.author)` which should instead be `await open_account(member)`

Now if you want to have to specify which user account you want to open every time you call the function you can try this:

```py
    @client.command()
    async def check(ctx,member:discord.Member):
        await open_account(member)
        users = await get_bank_data()

        wallet_amt = users[str(member.id)]["wallet"]
        bank_amt = users[str(member.id)]["bank"]

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = f"{member}'s balance",
            Colour = discord.Colour.red()
        )
        embed.set_author(name=member)
        embed.add_field(name='Wallet', value= wallet_amt, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='Bank', value= bank_amt, inline=False)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

or if you still want to have the option to show your own account as well as the member's account, you can try this.

```py
    @client.command()
    async def check(ctx, member:discord.Member= None):
        if member != None:
            await open_account(member)
            users = await get_bank_data()

            wallet_amt = users[str(member.id)]["wallet"]
            bank_amt = users[str(member.id)]["bank"]

            embed = discord.Embed(
                title = f"{member}'s balance",
                Colour = discord.Colour.red()
            )
            embed.set_author(name=member)
            embed.add_field(name='Wallet', value= wallet_amt, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Bank', value= bank_amt, inline=False)
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            user = ctx.author
            await open_account(user)
            users = await get_bank_data()

            wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
            bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

            embed = discord.Embed(
                title = f"{user}'s balance",
                Colour = discord.Colour.red()
            )
            embed.set_author(name=user)
            embed.add_field(name='Wallet', value= wallet_amt, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name='Bank', value= bank_amt, inline=False)
            await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```